# NSArray to va_list arguments and string format XCode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

So far I've been using this code snippet:

```
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format array:(NSArray*)arguments
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [arguments count]);
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:sizeof(id) * [arguments count]];
    [arguments getObjects:(__unsafe_unretained id *)data.mutableBytes range:range];

    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:data.mutableBytes];
    return result;
}
```

however since update to xcode 8, I'm receiving **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**. It's probably because some values passed in array are `NSTaggedPointerString *` but I'm not sure. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I am trying to convert a NSArray to va_list (to call the exact method you propose) with no luck up to now.

Comment: @Panayotis it's been a while. I can dig a little bit deeper in my old repos. As far as I remember I figured it out somehow.

Comment: @PiotrGawłowski could you clarify "somehow" please ;-)